# If data in column A is similar in two excel files, save similar data and delete all other data in the 2nd file

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row, similarity

I have a parent excel file with a forever changing range of point locations manually inputted into column A. For this example let's say 11.

```
Point
    P1
    P13
    P20
    P5
    P17
    P8
    P10
    P11
    P3
    P7
    P4
```

I have a 2nd excel file with another forever changing range of point locations and columns for each location. This file includes the points from the 1st file with other data in the (x) number of columns.

```
   Point Data1 Data2 Data3 Data4 Data5
   P1       a      b     c     d     e
   P2       a      b     c     d     e
   P3       a      b     c     d     e
   P4       a      b     c     d     e
   P5       a      b     c     d     e
   P6       a      b     c     d     e
   P7       a      b     c     d     e
   P8       a      b     c     d     e
   P9       a      b     c     d     e
   P10      a      b     c     d     e
   P11      a      b     c     d     e
   P12      a      b     c     d     e
   P13      a      b     c     d     e
   P14      a      b     c     d     e
   P15      a      b     c     d     e
   P16      a      b     c     d     e
   P17      a      b     c     d     e
   P18      a      b     c     d     e
   P19      a      b     c     d     e
   P20      a      b     c     d     e
```

I would like a push button on the first file to clear the second file of all points that do not exist in the first file while keeping title in the 1st row. Output would look like:

```
Point Data1 Data2 Data3 Data4 Data5
P1       a      b     c     d     e
P3       a      b     c     d     e
P4       a      b     c     d     e
P5       a      b     c     d     e
P7       a      b     c     d     e
P8       a      b     c     d     e
P10      a      b     c     d     e
P11      a      b     c     d     e
P13      a      b     c     d     e
P17      a      b     c     d     e
P20      a      b     c     d     e
```

The files will be in the same directory but I would like the user to be able to select the 2nd file to perform the search and delete.

It may be more simple to extract each point and corresponding row and save to a new sheet rather than delete all other points and data. That would be suitable as well. I know how to do this manually with VLOOKUP but I would like to automate it in VBA for other users.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you got any experience with vba? For if you know how to manually get the results and use the macro recorder to record every step you make, then you’re more than half way there.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this:

```
Sub mysub()
    Dim parentWb As Workbook, secondWb As Workbook

    Set parentWb = Workbooks.Open("parentWbPath\parentWbName.xlsx") ' adjust 'parent' workbook path and name to suit your needs
    Set secondWb = Workbooks.Open("secondWbPath\secondWbName.xlsx")' adjust 'secondWB' workbook path and name to suit your needs

    Dim filters As Variant
    With parentWb.Worksheets(1) 'assuming 'parent' workbook data are in its 1st worksheet
        filters = Application.Transpose(.Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value)
    End With

    Dim iRow As Long        
    With secondWb.Worksheets(1) 'assuming 'secodnWb' workbook data to be processed are in its 1st worksheet
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filters, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            For iRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row To 2 Step -1
                .Rows(iRow).Hidden = Not .Rows(iRow).Hidden
            Next
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Power Query**. It is an add-in for Excel 2010+ (by default in 2016 known as Get & Transform) that you can download an activate easily. There you can connect directly your sources of data and you will have a lot of tools to transform your data.

In your case, you can transform the first table as a `List` and use it as a filter for your data.

In the **Query Editor** > **Home** > **Advance Editor** you can paste this code (unofficialy known as M code)

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Main"]}[Content], //Main Table
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Filter"]}[Content], //Filter Table
    Filter = Source2[Point], //Covert Filter table in a List
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each List.Contains(Filter, [Point])) //Use the list as a filter
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

or follow this steps:

[image]

Even you can unpivot your data for future analysis:

[image]